# How to return XML data from a JSP?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, xml-parsing

From a jsp page I have to return xml data.

I fetch a record from the database and display in the Jsp. I have to return a display record in xml. And I have to do both display in jsp and same time return a record in xml.

I already did a display process and struck to return in xml:

```
<%
        String selectsql = null;
    DBConnection DBCon = null;
    Connection Con = null;      
    String maprule = null;
        PreparedStatement pstm = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        String snomedid = request.getParameter("snomedcode");
        String snomedname = request.getParameter("snomednames");

        try {
            DBCon = new DBConnection();
            Con = DBCon.getConnection();
            selectsql = "SELECT referencedComponentId,sctName,mapTarget,icdName,mapRule,refid FROM snomedicd10map WHERE referencedComponentId=? or sctName=? ";
            pstm = Con.prepareStatement(selectsql);
            pstm.setString(1, snomedid);
            pstm.setString(2, snomedname);
            resultSet = pstm.executeQuery();
%>

    <h2 align="center">
        <font><strong>SNOMED CT TO ICD 10 </strong></font>
    </h2>

    <div style='min-height: 40px'>
        <table id="tblMain" width="100%" class='table1' border=0
            cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='topmargin: -5px'>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='4' style='text-align: right;'>
                <!--    <input type="button" value="Back" onclick="goback();" style="background-color: #3399ff;color:#ffffff" /> -->    
                    <button onclick="goBack()" style="background-color: #3399ff;color:#ffffff">Back</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='headerText' style='height: 25px'>
                <td class='tdcellblue' style='width: 10%'>SNOMED</td>
                <td class='tdcellblue' style='width: 40%'>SNOMED Name</td>
                <td class='tdcellblue' style='width: 10%'>ICD-10</td>
                <td class='tdcellblue' style='width: 40%'>ICD Name</td>
            </tr>
            <%
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    //String maprule = null;
                    maprule = (resultSet.getString("mapRule"));
                    if (maprule.matches("OTHERWISE TRUE")
                            || maprule.matches("TRUE")) {
            %>

            <tr>
                <td><%=resultSet.getString("referencedComponentId")%></td>
                <td><%=resultSet.getString("sctName")%></td>
                <td><%=resultSet.getString("mapTarget")%></td>
                <td><%=resultSet.getString("icdName")%></td>
            </tr>

            <%
                }
                }
            %>
        </table>

    </div>

        <% 
        if(request.getParameter("hiderefineproblem")==null  && maprule.matches("OTHERWISE TRUE")){ %> 

        <input type="button" value="Refine Problem" onclick="return showHide();" style="background-color: #3399ff;color:#ffffff;" />
        <%}%>    

     <div id="showHideDiv" style="display: none;"> 

        <p>Would one of the following diagnoses apply? Choose the most
            specific one:</p> 
        <FORM ACTION="snomedMapping.jsp#newres" METHOD="POST">
        <%
            pstm = Con.prepareStatement(selectsql);
            pstm.setString(1, snomedid);
            pstm.setString(2, snomedname);
            resultSet = pstm.executeQuery();
            boolean bSubmit=false;
            int refid=0;
            String[] pipe=null;
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                 refid=resultSet.getInt("refid");
                 pipe= resultSet.getString("mapRule").split("\\|");

                if (pipe.length > 1){
                    bSubmit=true;
        %>      

            <input type="radio" id="radioList" value="<%=refid%>" name="refId"/>            
            <tr><%=pipe[1]%></tr>
             <br /> 

        <%
            }
            }           
        %>

        <%if(bSubmit){%>
        <input type="hidden" name='hiderefineproblem' value='yes'/> 
        <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Submit" style="background-color: #3399ff;color:#ffffff;"> 
        <%}%>

        </FORM>
          </div>

    <script>

        function showHide() {
            var ele = document.getElementById("showHideDiv")
            if (ele.style.display == "block") {
                ele.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                ele.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
        /* function goback(){
            window.location.href='/mobiledoc/jsp/catalog/xml/migration/snomedMapping/snomedIndex.jsp';
        } */
        function goBack() {
            window.history.back();
        }
    </script>


    <h2 align="center">
        <font><strong></strong></font>
    </h2>

    <div style='min-height: 40px' id="newres">
    <!--  <table id="tblMain" width="100%" class='table1' border=0
            cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='topmargin: -5px'>

            <tr class='headerText' style='height: 25px'>
                <td class='tdcellblue' style='width: 10%'>SNOMED</td>
                <td class='tdcellblue' style='width: 40%'>SNOMED Name</td>
                <td class='tdcellblue' style='width: 10%'>ICD-10</td>
                <td class='tdcellblue' style='width: 40%'>ICD Name</td>
            </tr> -->
            <table>
            <%              
                String str=request.getParameter("refId");
                if(str.length()>0){
                refid=Integer.parseInt(str);

                //resultSet=Root.EcwCloseResultSet(resultSet);
                //pstm=Root.EcwClosePreparedStatement(pstm);

                selectsql = "SELECT * FROM snomedicd10map WHERE refid=?";
                pstm =  pstm = Con.prepareStatement(selectsql);
                pstm.setInt(1,refid);
                resultSet = pstm.executeQuery();
                while (resultSet.next()) {
            %>          
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2' style='font-weight:bold;'>SNOMED</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%=resultSet.getString("referencedComponentId")%>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td><%=resultSet.getString("sctName")%></td>                
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2' style='font-weight:bold;'>Target ICD</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%=resultSet.getString("mapTarget")%>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td><%=resultSet.getString("icdName")%></td>
            </tr>
            <%
                 }
                }
            %>

        </table>
    </div>

<%  }
```

How to implement it? I need to create one more page or in same page.

Comment: Your last sentence in nonsense. Your spelling is terrible, I can't believe you didn't learn in the elementary school that sentences start with capital case, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning HTML text from the JSP, you just return XML text.

The code that is provided has HTML tags and JSP code to create the HTML document structure and content.

The XML version of the JSP will have XML tags and JSP code to create the XML document structure and content.

Comment: yes  i use xml tag but i cant display in front end UI so what to do ,

Comment: If you want to display XML data in a browser, the usual approach is to create a CSS style sheet that would tell the browser how to display each XML element.